# Does signing and encryption bring any benefits for OCP UA over HTTPS?

Tags: opc-ua

I am reading the OPC UA specification and there is one thing I am confused about:

When using HTTPS as a transport protocol, the secure channel is already established by the TLS.

In this case, does it make sense to use any other security mode than None?

What would be the benefit to encrypt or sign the messages over an already secured channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SecurityPolicy becomes mostly irrelevant when using HTTPS transport.

From Part 6 when discussing HTTPS:

> The SecurityPolicy shall be specified, however, it only affects the algorithms used for signing
> the Nonces during the CreateSession/ActivateSession handshake. A SecurityPolicy of None
> indicates that the Nonces do not need to be signed.

For what it's worth... the only transport you'll find widely supported in the real world is the OPC UA TCP transport with binary encoding. This is the only combination that is mandatory for implementations.

Comment: Many thanks, Kevin! Your note about the support of profiles is very important. As TCP+bin is mandatory, I don't really see any point in providing any other stacks. Similar to authentication methods: The specification talks about the support of JWT but I did not find any client that would support it. Your Milo project seems to provide partial support of Issued Tokens, but there's a lot left to be implemented by the server providers, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you use HTTPS for transport, TLS will define encryption, as you have understood.

But, OPC UA is also enabling Application Authentication using Application Instance Certificates. If you use OPC UA SecurityMode=None, the Application Authentication is ignored. In order to enable Application Authentication with HTTPS, you will need to use at least SecurityMode=Sign, although the message signing or security is not really necessary on top of TLS.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this is why SignAndEncrypt makes not much sense with HTTPS.